# Setting the spacing for an ol list item

Tags: css

In the following code, I find the space between number **1** and content **DIY SMS Export V1.05 has been released** is a little width,
how can I set the margin between between number and content with CSS?

And more, the webpage have same UI both IE 10.0 and FireFox 21.0 as the following image.

[image]

but in IE 10.0 compatible mode, the UI changed as the following image. the left margin increased, why?

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">
       li.A {
          list-style-type: decimal;
          font-weight: bold;
           margin-bottom:15px;          
        }

        li.B{
          list-style-type:upper-alpha;
          font-weight:normal;
          margin-top:4px;
          margin-bottom:4px;   

        }

        ol.C {

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li class="A">DIY SMS Export V1.05 has been released
                <ol class="C">
                    <li class="B">Add the function to delete sms selected</li>
                </ol>
            </li>

            <li class="A">DIY SMS Export V1.04 has been released
                <ol class="C">
                    <li class="B">Add chinese language support</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>  
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before HTML5, in HTML4.01, the default CSS for User Agent was only suggested. The needed indentation for lists and especially lists in lists was achieved either with `margin-left: 40px` or `padding-left: 40px` in Firefox and IE (and I mean Netscape and IE...)

So a light reset as in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJbAg) will take care of the difference.

CSS

```
ol, ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ol, ul {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that ol list item can't work well in IE 6.0 ?

Comment: It works fine. Only the default CSS is different (the styles you still see when you deactivate all Styles via the Display menu I think like big H1, bullets in front of LI, etc). This default CSS is the first thing to be overriden by YOUR styles but you first have to know which styles are applied by this and that browser. ;) That's the purpose of "reset CSS" (I'll let you search the term here on SO and on Google) (or minimalist http://www.knacss.com by my friend and boss) to have just a common base (or nuke every default style, depends on the solution chosen)

Comment: Here both margin-left and padding-left are set to null (so it's now 0 in every browser and not 40px anymore) and then set to 20px with one method, the same for every browser (margin-left is slightly more practical than padding-left but both work in IE6+).

Comment: Thanks! you are right, the default css effect the result. Sometimes a default css work in IE 9.0, somtimes a default css work in IE6.0, I don't know which css and when these css  effect the style in different IE version :(